# Kotlin Generics for collection extension function

Tags: kotlin, generics

Lets say we have an extension function like this

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.fillWith(default: T, size: Int) = apply {

    if (this is ArrayList) {
        ensureCapacity(size)
    }
    while (size < newSize) add(default)
}
```

Our goal here is to be able to fill any list with default value `T`, but return `this` so that we can continue chain other methods or maybe just assign it to a field in one expression like this `val data = LinkedList<String>().fillWith("", 42)`

Unfortunately our return type unsurprisingly is `MutableList` is there a way to return actual most specific type? so that i could define one generic extension function but be able to do things like

```
val data1 : LinkedList<String> = LinkedList().fillWith("", 42)
val data2 : ArrayList<String> = LinkedList().fillWith("", 42)
```

Comment: extension functions works just as static methods in java, so applicable only to the type on which it is defined.

Comment: Try this: `fun <R, T: MutableList<R>> T.fillWith(default: R, size: Int) : T`

Comment: @Pawel oh my bad, somehow I was thinking about creating a new list, not mutating the original. This should definitely be ok

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem of not being able to infer the List type when tagged onto a constructor call.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but for this you can just add `<String>` at the constructor call site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Pawel, you can make the function generic in the list type itself:

```
fun <R, T: MutableList<R>> T.fillWith(default: R, newSize: Int) : T = apply {
    if (this is ArrayList<*>) {
        ensureCapacity(size)
    }
    while (size < newSize) add(default)
}
```

You will then have to specify the type of the elements in your list on the call site in the constructor call, because the compiler can't infer it:

```kotlin
val data1 = LinkedList<String>().fillWith("", 42)
val data2 = ArrayList<String>().fillWith("", 42)
```

Note that you can also simply make your function return `Unit` and use `apply` on the call site.

Also, if you don't care that much about the specific list implementation, there are already built-in functions [List()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list.html) and [MutableList()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list.html) for the specific use case of initialization like this:

```kotlin
// creates a list of 42 empty strings
val list = MutableList(42) { "" }

// creates a list of 42 strings "elt 0", "elt 1" etc.
val list = MutableList(42) { index -> "elt $index" }
```

Comment: i do care, imo they should not do things like MutableList and rather do Specifically named ones... for a long time i had no idea that mutable map is LinkedHashMap rather than hash map ) 

Programmers should always know what exact structure they are allocating.

Comment: @vach I would argue the opposite. Programmers should almost never have to care about this, unless they have specific requirements. Defaults should be defined so that most common use cases are covered. `ArrayList` and `LinkedHashMap` are decent defaults. This is exactly what abstraction is about in general, this is one application of the principle.

Comment: LinkedHashMap is one of the slowest and heaviest structures for a Map you can use, this is how you end up with garbage software that is slow and demanding in memory, because programmers using it did not care to know that they are allocating inefficient data structure...

Comment: Anyway i'm happy you think that way, otherwise my job of optimising jvm software would be obsolete ) Applications where 120+ threads are running cos programmers "shouldn't care" about this, or 90% of heap is near empty LinkedHashMaps is the result.

Comment: Yeah `LinkedHashMap` was also a bit surprising to me at first, I think the idea was to err on the "safety"  side, because people iterate maps and expect insertion order. Tbh it's not that big of a deal in most cases - not everything is a hot path, and a lot of those are on TLABs anyway. And no it's definitely not the slowest map out there in general (it's still a hashmap after all).

Comment: But anyway I think you misread my point. I'm talking about abstraction here, as in writing code that expresses your intent more than the details of how it will work. I've seen people "optimize" things by writing `new StringBuilder().append("1").append("2").toString()` instead of `"1" + "2"` because """StringBuilder is faster than +""". I had to explain that it was the same thing (at the time) and that they misunderstood the advice. More importantly, using `+` allows the compiler to choose better implementations later... and guess what, Java 9 did just that.

Comment: Yes i am totally for abstraction layer that java didn't do, MutableList vs immutable List is awesome, i am only against generic sounding builders, because people end up using things they didn't. Also yes absolutely people should never try to outsmart JIT, however allocating LInkedHashMaps has nothing to do with it, its just bad idea in my book.